# under same username I can not post?

Tags: django, django-models, django-allauth

I am using Django 2.07. In my application after posting the first post, the second post it is not taking a post under the same username (I'm using Django all-auth). At Django admin, it shows me "this username already exits."

this is my profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    PUBLIC = 'Public'
    PRIVATE = 'Private'
    INITIATIVE ='Initiative'
    PRIVATE_STARTUP = 'Private and Startup'
    INITIAL_KEYWORD = (
    (PUBLIC, 'Public'),
    (PRIVATE, 'Private'),
    (INITIATIVE, 'Initiative'),
    (PRIVATE_STARTUP, 'Private and Startup'),
    )
    Type_of_account = models. NullBooleanField('Personal account', 
    help_text="by default this is Business account")
    user_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_image', blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False, default=None)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    additional_url = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True )
    Headquarter = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    stock_market = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    established = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, default=None)
    investors = RichTextField(null=True, blank=True)
    about_details = RichTextField(null=False, blank=False, default=None)
    Type_of_company = models.CharField(
     max_length=20,
     null=True, 
     blank=True, 
     choices=INITIAL_KEYWORD, 
     default=PRIVATE_STARTUP)
```

This is my main-model.

```
class MainModel(models.Model):
    I_THINK = 'I think'
    GOOD_PART = 'Good part'
    BAD_PART ='Bad part'
    PROTOTYPE = 'Prototype'
    FEEDBACK = 'Feedback'
    INFO = 'Info'
    REVIEW = 'Review'
    ASK = 'Ask'
    FINACIAL_MARKET = 'Financial market'
    INITIAL_KEYWORD_FOR_THOUGHTS = (
    (I_THINK, 'I THINK'),
    (FEEDBACK, 'FEEDBACK'),
    (GOOD_PART, 'GOOD PART'),
    (BAD_PART, 'BAD PART'),
    (PROTOTYPE, 'PROTOTYPE'),
    (INFO, 'INFO'),
    (REVIEW, 'REVIEW'),
    (ASK, 'ASK'), 
    (FINACIAL_MARKET, 'FINANCIAL MARKET')
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    pub_time = models.DateTimeField('Publish time', auto_now=True)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
##
    micro_thought = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True) 
    Initial_keyword_for_thoughts = models.CharField(
    max_length=300,
    null=True, 
    blank=True, 
    choices=INITIAL_KEYWORD_FOR_THOUGHTS, 
 default=I_THINK
 )
```

What kind of changes I have to make at main-models user field?
how I can solve this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [OneToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) field to relate user to Post. Using OnetoOne field a user can have atmost one post. That is the issue. Change it to **[ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)** relation.

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

Comment: Appreciate your help...@a_k_v